# How to send a BatchRequest to google API with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, google-api, odata

I am working with the Google API to automate tasks for distribution groups.
I understand how to send individual requests, but I want to be able to send BatchRequests, and this seems to be a challenge as the format is not consistent like for example all JSON so i can convert the body once and make my request.
I am reading through the documentation from Google and I cant figure out how to achieve that with Powershell.
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/batch

I see there is already a .NET library for that, but I struggle to understand how to use it.
https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis/latest/api/Google.Apis.Requests.BatchRequest.html

I cant understand how I can do nested HTTP request inside a HTTP request with PowerShell.
I have no idea how I can even write it, so here is a draft that I am thinking over, and I will be editing throughout this post.

```
$batchUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch/admin/directory_v1'

$header = @{
    "Content-type"  = "multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_test"
    "Authorization" = "Bearer <token>"
}

$psBody = [ordered] @{
    method = "POST /admin/directory/v1/groups/vtest@gs.vasil.com/members"
    "content-type" = "application/json"
    email = "vas@gs.vasil.com"
    role = "MEMBER"
}

$JSONbody = $psBody | ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $batchUrl -Method POST -Headers $header -Body $JSONbody
```

I really want to understand that OData structure, any documentation/guide reference are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, the format needed was literally what Google posted, therefore I just had to adjust the body to what I want.
The example bellow is just Prove of Concept and would need some functions to automate the population from an Array.

```
$URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch/admin/directory_v1'

$boundary = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString();
$LF = "`r`n";

$header = @{
    "Content-type"  = "multipart/mixed; boundary=$boundary"
    "Authorization" = "Bearer <token>"
}

$request1 = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
    email = "vas1@gs.vasil.com"
    role  = "MEMBER"
} | ConvertTo-Json

$request2 = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
    email = "vas2@gs.vasil.com"
    role  = "MEMBER"
} | ConvertTo-Json

$nestedBody = (
    "--$boundary",
    "Content-Type: application/http$LF",
    "POST /admin/directory/v1/groups/vtest@gs.vasil.com/members",
    "Content-Type: application/json$LF",
    "$($request1)$LF",
    "--$boundary--",
    "Content-Type: application/http$LF",
    "POST /admin/directory/v1/groups/vtest@gs.vasil.com/members",
    "Content-Type: application/json$LF",
    "$($request2)$LF",
    "--$boundary--"
) -join $LF

$sendRequest = @{
    Uri         = $URL
    header      =  $header
    Method      = "Post"
    Body        = $nestedBody
}

Invoke-RestMethod @sendRequest
```

The way I got to that conclusions was by installing the `Fiddler` Proxy and see how my request look like in practice, check screenshot bellow.

[image]